# Retrieve password for User.Identity.Name from C# code

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

I have a .NET MVC web project setup where I have used basic authentication on the project. I need to encode the user entered password to access a service I use in my project. I get the username in the code using `User.Identity.Name` but how do I retrieve what password the user entered on the browser prompt?

Comment: I don't think you can get it from the built in objects. You can take what they typed from the page and pass it into a windows principal object but as far as I know there is no way to do what you are asking.

Comment: What about be an alternate authentication mechanism I can use then? I *have* to get access to both the user name and their password in my code since I use them to access a service in my project.

Comment: Like I said you can create a network credential with data the user gives you via a form (or stored somewhere) and use that. Without knowing the details of your app there are just way too many different ways to approach this. Typically when accessing a service you have a non-priviledged service account do the actual service work and you control access to it via standard authentication \ authorization methods (like forms auth or something).